# oracle RAC TAF session Failover

Tags: oracle

I use two nodes oracle RAC, I use a progress to connect to the database to do some data writing, while insert 100 rows I do a commit. I use the client-side TAF configuration of Session Failover.
So if the node 1 fail over, and I just insert 50 rows and do not execute the commit, when it automatically shift to the node 2, all the data I insert will be lost or will be insert again in the node 2, so the application of the progress will not concern about it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All the data will be rollbacked for all transactional statement (insert, update ,delete). You have to configure in the source code that if failure occur then check for connection with other available node and insert process is re triggered from the code. Application will not be effected if it is configured in source code.